# Hibernate UserType being ignored by Oracle

Tags: oracle, hibernate, usertype

I am writing an application with Hibernate (using Hibernate 3 at the moment) that should be database independent; at the moment I'm working with Derby and Oracle (version 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.4.0).

Several of my database columns hold boolean values.  A decision was made long ago to store these as "Y" or "N" and then map them to Java Boolean values using a UserType.  There are a large number of data files used for unit tests that depend on this configuration, and so I do not want to change it.

Everything works fine when the application uses the Derby database to construct an object containing one of these columns using Session.load(); in particular, the UserType code is executed for each boolean column.

However, when connected to Oracle, the UserType code for nullSafeGet is never called.  This leads an exception being thrown: `org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter SEVERE:  Fail to convert to internal representation`, with the following stack trace:

```
at oracle.jdbc.driver.CharCommonAccessor.getBoolean(CharCommonAccessor.java:185)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCharAccessor.getBoolean(T4CCharAccessor.java:699)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.getBoolean(OracleResultSetImpl.java:626)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSet.getBoolean(OracleResultSet.java:386)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BitTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(BitTypeDescriptor.java:64)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:64)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:253)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:249)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:229)
...
```

The fact that the code is in AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet rather than the nullSafeGet of my user type seems to indicate that my code is not being called; setting a breakpoint in the debugger confirms this.

I have set the hibernate.dialect property to `org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect` and am using `oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver` as the JDBC driver.

Comment: How do you configure Hibernate to use your `UserType`?

Comment: @axtavt  I'm using JPA annotations:
(at)Basic
(at)Type(type="edu.hope.cs.surveys.dao.pojo.YesNo")
public boolean getAnonymous ()

Couldn't get SO to let me put the actual (at) sign for the annotations

Comment: I've found the problem with this.  It turns out that one of my Boolean columns was not annotated with the Type annotation needed to use the custom type.  Apparently the Derby JDBC driver is able to successfully convert a value of "Y" or "N" to a Boolean, while Oracle's is not.  Unfortunately it was the first entity encountered, and so setting a breakpoint in the custom type's nullSafeGet didn't unmask the problem.  Sorry to post the false alarm, but hopefully someone else stumbles across this post if they make the same mistake I did.